# ScrollableResults not initializing eager collections in Hibernate 5?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, scrollableresults

I've got an eagerly fetched one-to-many collection inside of an entity:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_COL_1", referencedColumnName="keyValue1"),
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_COL_2", referencedColumnName="keyValue2"),
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_COL_3", referencedColumnName="keyValue3"),
})
private List<ChildRecord> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

This works normally when not using `ScrollableResults`: `query.getResultList()`. Hibernate fetches the parent entity, then subsequently fetches all the children. I can see this when SQL printing is turned on.

However, when using `ScrollableResults`:

```
query.setReadOnly(true)
    .setFetchSize(10000)
    .setCacheable(false)
    .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY)
```

... it's *not* eagerly fetched. As a result, we reference the collection by calling the getter after the session is closed, and we get our lovely error: `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.foo.bar.Parent.children, could not initialize proxy - no Session`. Obviously we *could* just manually invoke the getter before closing the results, but I feel like that's a hack and probably not the right solution.

**And so I ask:** why is it not eagerly fetching the collection when using `ScrollableResults`?

I debugged Hibernate a bit and discovered that the `loadCounter` is set to 1 when `context.initializeNonLazyCollections` is invoked (which is supposed to load the children). Because it's not zero, it doesn't initialize any of them. When using `ScrollableResults`, manipulation of `loadCounter` is done inside of `ScrollableResultsImpl.prepareCurrentRow` via the `beforeLoad()` and `afterLoad()` methods. *However*, within `Loader.loadSingleRow` (which `ScrollableResultsImpl` calls), there is no `afterLoad()` called before `initializeNonLazyCollections()` is called on the context. Thus, `loadCounter` is still stuck at 1, and none of the collections are loaded.

This is as opposed to the non-scrollable case where `Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections` *does* call `afterLoad()` prior to calling `initializeNonLazyCollections()`. This sets `loadCounter` back to zero, and thus it can loop over the children and fetch them.

Is this a bug in Hibernate? Am I missing something here? This worked fine in Hibernate 4.3.11, but appears to not work in 5.4.24 and 5.6.8. It seems like [this change](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/cc01f2561dbca95bd58048f85e283ba1719ee588) is the one that broke it; using a version prior seems to resolve this particular problem, as does invoke the getters manually before closing the session.

Note: A open ticket ([HHH-14383](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14383)) is already open with hibernate regarding the issue.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm stuck someplace similar.

Comment: 'I feel like that's a hack and probably not the right solution' - well, depends on what you define as 'right'. Performance-wise it's exactly the same, since there's no way to get the parents' and children's data in a single query anyway